# Workaround for unsupported date format when it comes to BETWEEN?

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a date (its a `varchar(30)`) in a format, like this

```
d.m.y
```

, where

```
day = a day without leading zeros
m   = a month with leading zeros
y   = last two numbers of a year
```

And a table, that looks like this

```
id | date     | price

1  | 7.04.14  | 10

2  | 8.04.14  | 20

3  | 9.04.14  | 30
```

And when a query is executed,

```
SELECT `price` FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '7.04.14' AND '9.04.14';
```

it returns nothing

The thing: I cannot change a date format, and I have to get prices between two dates. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Change the data type to `date`. This is the best solution. It is easy to query and is really fast since it can make use of indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parse the dates.

```
SELECT price
  FROM `table`
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%m.%y')
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(...) AND STR_TO_DATE(...)
```

Also, consider taking a look at [the manual page for STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

But as @juergen d writes, it is far better to use date types.

Comment: well, I've tried running `SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%b.%y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('7.04.14', '%d.%b.%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('9.04.14', '%d.%b.%y')` and it returned nothing, while should return 2 rows. Did I miss something?

Comment: Try running `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('7.04.14', '%d.%b.%y')` and `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9.04.14', '%d.%b.%y')` to see what they output.

Comment: They both return `NULL`

Comment: My bad. You need %m in stead of %b.